# How to allow Out of Office Email auto reply from C#

Tags: c#, email

I have a C# method to send email and I want to get the auto replied out of office email to sender or reply to users. Here is my code it does not work.

I see I get out of office email reply if send from outlook, but what is the problem with bellow code?

```
    public void SendEmail()
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("my host server", 25);
        var sender = "sender";
        var to = "receiver";
        var replyTo = sender;

        try
        {
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

            msg.From = new MailAddress(sender);
            msg.Subject = "Test auto reply from C#";
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(replyTo))
            {
                msg.ReplyToList.Add(replyTo);
            }

            msg.Body = "This is from C# email server to test auto reply.";

            client.Send(msg);

            msg.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            client.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Who knows? You're catching and suppressing all possible exceptions. There's no good reason for that. *Are* you getting an exception? If so, it probably tells you what's wrong already.

Comment: @hvd It is not raising any exception, sending email successfully but if the receiver has any Out of Office auto reply it does not get in sender email in box.

Comment: @UtpalKumarDas are you saying it works, but if the receiver has an "out of the office" reply, it doesn't work? Don't really see how that's related to your code, or sending an email for that matter. Maybe check the receiver's inbox settings. Try sending an email from an existing interface (Outlook, Gmail, etc) using the same host server and see what happens to the email.

Comment: The problem has been resolved, actually we used the from(msg.From) address noreply@domain  that is why it did not send to our target sender. Now we are using noreply@domain as msg.Sender and target sender with msg.From.

Answer (score 0):

We have solved the issue by bellow code:

```
    public void SendEmail()
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("my host server", 25);
        var sender = "noreply@domain.com";
        var from = "actual sender";
        var to = "receiver";
        var replyTo = sender;

        try
        {
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

            msg.From = new MailAddress(from);
            msg.Sender = new MailAddress(sender);

            msg.Subject = "Test auto reply from C#";
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(replyTo))
            {
                msg.ReplyToList.Add(replyTo);
            }

            msg.Body = "This is from C# email server to test auto reply.";

            client.Send(msg);

            msg.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            client.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Email address "noreply@domain.com" has been used just as company address without any reply considering no reply option.